# getting processing failed with an error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer error in pyspark

Tags: python, postgresql, pyspark, psycopg2

I am using pyspark to connect with the Postgres database using psycopg2 library.
my code snippet is as follows:

```
    con = psycopg2.connect(database=db,
                           user=user,
                           password=pwd,
                           host=hostname,
                           port=db_port)
```

but while processing a large no. of records gives errors like below  after processing for about 60 mins:

> **failed with an error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer**

I have tried to increase the connection time by using attributes like tcp_timeout, and connect_timeout but it didn't help me in this case.

Does anyone have better solution for this?

I am expecting connection to be active till all my records are processed.

Comment: Is pyspark actually relevant here? It's not used to connect to a database.

Comment: can you provide us the full snippet? and the full stacktrace?

Comment: @AlexK yeah, pyspark is not actually very much relevant. issue is with connection

Comment: @Kulasangar, this pyspark code I have written inside AWS GLUE ETL pyspark script. I have only that much stack trace and code.